# Método de ordenamiento Shell en Visual Basic

Tags: array, vb.net

Anteriormente había publicado esto, el problema de este código es que realmente no hace lo que debe hacer, ordenar los números en el listbox, alguna sugerencia o ayuda a resolverlo

```
If rbshell.Checked = True Then
    entero = n + 1
    While entero > 1
        entero = (entero / 2)
        band = True
        While band = True
            band = False
            i = 0
            While (i + entero) < n
                If lstnumeros.Items(i) > lstnumeros.Items(i + entero) Then
                    Auxiliar = lstnumeros.Items(i)
                    lstnumeros.Items(i) = lstnumeros.Items(i + entero)
                    lstnumeros.Items(i + entero) = Auxiliar
                    band = True
                End If
                i = i + 1
            End While
        End While
    End While
    lstnumeros.Show()
End If
```

Comment: Por favor, no dupliques las preguntas. Sigue con la pregunta que hiciste, agrega los datos necesarios alla para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: afortunadamente ya resolví mi problema

Comment: Y es totalmente valido, si escribis una buena respuesta explicando tu problema y la solucion.